# PHP Regex to get multiline value out of Email Header

Tags: php, regex, email

I have a quick question. How do I get a value from a email header that is on multiple lines?

Here is an example subject value in the email header:

```
Subject: =?UTF-8?B?RGVhbHMgZm9yIHRoZSBEYXkgfCBQbHVzLCBzYXZlIDI1JSBvbiA=?=
   =?UTF-8?B?bmVhcmx5IEVWRVJZVEhJTkch?=
MIME-Version: 1.0
```

I am using the following regex but it only returns a single line:

```
'/Subject: (.*)/i'
```

Now I tried using the following and returns both lines, however when the subject is only one line it returns other header information that is not wanted (MIME-Version...).

```
'/Subject: (.*)(\n\s*(.*))/i'
```

How can I modify the regex to only pull the second line if it starts with spaces (\s*) and can span multiple lines, i.e. if the "Subject" is varied in length.

Thanks for your help!

**UPDATE SOLUTION**

Thanks to @G-Nugget below is a regex that will do what I want and group the result:

```
 /Subject: ((.*)(\n\s+(.*))*)/i
```

Comment: Use a library that parses mail header properly, see the PHP manual for existing options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second regex is close.  This modified version should do the trick:

```
/Subject: (.*)(\n\s+(.*))*/i
```

By switch the `*` in the middle to a `+`, there must be a space at the start of the line to grab it.  The `*` at the end allows the regex to match any number of lines as long as all but the first start with a space.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Unfortunately that doesn't seem to work if the subject is on a single line. It returns an empty array.

Comment: @thiesdiggity My bad, I'm updating my answer with a fix and bonus.

Comment: That works! I updated my question with the final regex. I modified it a little to combine the results.

Comment: Be carefull with this solution because it can match unexpectedly "AnythingSubject: ...". See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend to use regexp with "[m](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php)" modifier and "^" to search only at the begining of the line:

```php
/^Subject: (.*)(\n\s+(.*))*/im
```

to avoid matching completely different header than expected - for example:

"X-Subject" instead of "Subject"

"X-Google-DKIM-Signature" instead of "DKIM-Signature"